# Como transformar um espaço de cores rgb em hsv em R

Tags: r

Como eu faço para ler uma imagem de uma pasta, e transformá-la de rgb em hsv extraindo uma matriz de pixels para os parâmetros h, s e v (tudo pelo software R)??

Comment: Há uma função para isso, veja a página de ajuda `?rgb2hsv`.

Comment: Sim,sim...Não estou conseguindo buscar a imagem na pasta e anexá-la à função.

Comment: Primeiro deverá ler o ficheiro. Para isso existem diversas funções, como os ficheiros de gráficos têm certos formatos deverá ser necessário uma função de algum pacote. Qual o tipo de ficheiro?

Comment: Boa noite. Obrigado pela ajuda.